# How to iterate through a paginated jQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have a datatable where in I have set 100 rows to a page. Anyway, with jQuery -sending request to server etc., I have the data filled, for e.g. say one of the calls brings in 260 rows. Later when I have to perform some checks for each row for e.g. to see if some values have been selected or something like that, I need to iterate. So when I use fnGetNodes() or fnGetData() both seem to get only the first 100 rows of the table that is the 1st page rows. I want to be able to iterate all the 260 rows, because the user may have paged back and forth and made several selections/changes to the data. Any help is appreciated. I am using jQuery 1.4 version of DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but what we do is to temporarily expand the datatable so that all rows are shown, iterate, then revert back to the original length.

```
var origLength = dataTable.fnLengthChange();
dataTable.fnLengthChange( dataTable.fnPagingInfo().iTotal );
// Iterate here
dataTable.fnLengthChange( origLength );
```

Hope there's a more decent solution.